# SOAP UI installation error in HP-UX

Tags: installation, soapui

I am trying to install SOAP UI Pro-x64-4.6.1 in HP-UX but resulted in below Error.

## ./SoapUI-Pro-x64-4.6.1.sh

Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
./SoapUI-Pro-x64-4.6.1.sh: bin/unpack200: Execute permission denied.
Error unpacking jar files. The architecture or bitness (32/64)
of the bundled JVM might not match your machine.

Any Idea on how to rectify this.

HP-UX  B.11.23 U ia64
Java version 1.5.0.03

Regards,
Jai

Comment: If it is 'Pro' version, why not to ask support on SmartBear user forum? :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it seems like you are using a 64 bit operating system one thing you could try is to run the 32-bit installer.